# Black and white movie where a reptilian creature dropped on people and gave them boils

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I’m trying to recall the name of a black and white movie I watched as a child. I assume it was a film from the 50s or 60s. I remember a reptilian-looking creature that hid in trees and whenever someone stood below it, the creature would fall on that person’s back. Huge boils or lesions would appear and the person would ultimately die a slow and painful death. There was also a scene at a park and a few people were attacked by a swarm of these creatures.

Help me find this creature film! End my 15+ yrs search